# Laravel middleware Password Confirm change password_timeout

Tags: php, laravel, fortify

I was using this middleware:

```
Route::get('/{id}/edit',[PostController::class,'edit'])->name('post.edit')->middleware('password.confirm');
```

of laravel fortify so that it asks me for the password before accessing a route, but this depends on
`'password_timeout'=>10800` in **auth.php**, so I need it to ask me for password whenever the route calls, try to set the value to `'password_timeout'=>1,` but it is no longer possible to submit the form, it no longer returns Request validations from the controller. You could guide me to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: did you get any solution on this